# Is there any way to move my perspective in viewpoint as same as my camera is watching?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I'm curious about

Is there any way to move my perspective in viewpoint as same as camera is watching?

I've googled some, but the only one I could find is to move camera to which I'm watching now.

I want to do the reverse, I want my viewport just fit on what my camera is watching.

Answer (score 1):

You can snap your viewport to your active camera with the View Camera operation (as it's called in keybinding), which is, by default, bound to numpad 0.

Comment: Thanks! It really snaps my viewport, but I want it to be zoomed to fit my viewport and render result is just the same. Is is possible?

Comment: It was my mistake. It's perfect answer for me. Thanks!